# How to store variables in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express

How can I store a variable in Google Cloud Platform? Right now I am using a global variable that my routes share, but the values are off every time a request has been made to the route. I think it's because my server may have multiple instances running sharing the same variable. My application is using Node.js/Express.

My POST route sets the `new_posted_time` variable that `/display-message` uses:

```
var new_posted_time = 0;
app.post('/message', function (request, response) {
  message = request.body.Body;

  new_posted_time = new_posted_time + 1;

  console.log("This is the new time from POST: " + new_posted_time);
  response.send("<Response><Message>Heyyo!</Message></Response>");

});
```

My GET route gets the value for `new_posted_time` that was defined in `/message`.

```
app.get('/display-message', function(req,res){

    var last_updated_time = req.query.last_updated;

    function checkMessage() {
        var new_time = new_posted_time;
        console.log("Checking messaged with new time from GET: " + new_time);

        if(!last_updated_time || last_updated_time < new_time) {
            updateMessage(new_time);
        }
        else {
            console.log("No new messages at this time");
            myTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                checkMessage(res);
            }, 1000 * 10); //10 seconds
        }
    }

    function updateMessage() {
        console.log("Updating message now");
        var output = {
            success: 1,
            data: message,
            old_stamp: last_updated_time,
            new_stamp: new_stamp
        };

        return res.json(output);
    }

    checkMessage();

});
```

So I need to be able to store the shared variable `new_posted_time` somewhere in Google's database because the value is not consistent every time my application runs due to many instances running (which is my guess).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably store 'state' like this in a persistent store like [Google Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/). Here is an article on [implementing counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) with Google Cloud Datastore (its from the AppEngine Datastore API, but it is the same principle).

Storing state in your instances is a bad idea because not only will you have consistency problems between instances, you will also lose data when an instance is shutdown automatically by AppEngine.

Comment: If I store variables as entities in the datastore, is that the same thing as storing state in my instances? If yes, then what's the most effective/appropriate method in storing shared variables?

Comment: No using the datastore is not the same as 'storing state in your instances'. The difference is when you use the datastore you are writing data to disk using a service that will always be available, when you write to a shared variable you are storing data in memory, on a machine instance that can be shutdown arbitrarily by the autoscaler.

Comment: thanks! I'm a little confused on how to implement google datastore in my code. I see several ways to do this in Node.js but can't get it to work.